# How to keep focus on the select when clicking on it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, iframe, material-ui

When clicking on the Material Ui select it scrolls to top of the page every time within iframe.

I have created on react application which has select option for month and year. when i click on the select button it auto scrolls to the top of the page which is very annoying
This issue is occurring when i am loading react app within iframe only.
without iframe it is working fine

```
<Select
         
            variant="outlined"
            IconComponent={KeyboardArrowDown}
            labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
            style={{ marginRight: "10px", fontSize: Theme.typography.caption.fontSize}}
            placeholder={Content?.expiryMonthPlaceHolder}
            id="expirationMonth"
            value={expirationMonth}
            label="MM"
            className={classes.cardmonth}
            //   expirationMonth ? classes.cardmonth : classes.cardmonthEmpty
            // }
            onChange={e => {
              setExpirationMonth(e.target.value);
            }}
          >
            {months.map(month => (
              <MenuItem key={month} value={month}  autoFocus={true} style={{ fontSize: Theme.typography.caption.fontSize }}>
                {month}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </Select>
```

Comment: Is your "Select button" rendered as a `<button>` or a `<select>` ?

Comment: @NiceBooks It is material ui component so it has been rendered within div and options are loaded within ul > li

Comment: @NiceBooks No actually its not i have removed it still it is same

Comment: Does `setExpirationMonth` reload the iframe by chance ?

Comment: No @NiceBooks I think it is related to some issue within iframe select. If i use it without iframe it is working fine

Comment: Please post the code of `setExpirationMonth`.